# Generar 3 números aleatorios del 1 al 5, sin repetir, sumar los 3 y crear un premio

Tags: algoritmos

Necesito ayuda para crear un programa, necesito simular que 3 canicas caigan en 5 agujeros enumerados 1, 2, 3, 4 y 5; una vez tiradas las 3 canicas sumar la cantidad y entregar una serie de premios, dependiendo de la cantidad de puntos sumados.

ej. si la primera canica cae en el agujero 3, la segunda en el 4 y la tercera en el 5, sumaría 12 puntos; A lo cual es la cantidad máxima que puede sumarse, se le daría el premio mayor. así consecutivamente hasta llegar a 6 puntos.

Los premios serían:

12pts Peluche

11pts Palomitas

10pts Alcancía

9pts luchadores

8pts Rompecabezas

7pts Conejo

6pts Canicas

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio,nosotros no funcionamos así, debes colocar el código que tienes o que has usado y en caso de haber errores debes decir cuales son, te invito a que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que entiendas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganes tu primer medalla, además es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), saludos y ánimo

Comment: ademas debes agregar el lenguaje sobre el cual estas trabajando.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Nose si esto es lo que pedias, pero con este codigo se puede ganar hasta 15 puntos, asi que cambialo como veas.


    int n1= (int) (Math.random()*5+1);
    int n2= (int) (Math.random()*5+1);
    int n3= (int) (Math.random()*5+1);

    System.out.println(n1);
    System.out.println(n2);
    System.out.println(n3);

    int suma = n1+n2+n3;
    System.out.print(suma+" : ");

    if(suma==12){
        System.out.println("Has ganado un peluche");
    }
    else if(suma==11){
        System.out.println("Has ganado Palomitas");
    }
    else if(suma==10){
        System.out.println("Has ganado Alcancia");
    }
    else if(suma==9){
        System.out.println("Has ganado luchadores");
    }
    else if(suma==8){
        System.out.println("Has ganado Rompecabezas");
    }
    else if(suma==7){
        System.out.println("Has ganado conejo");
    }
    else if(suma==6){
        System.out.println("Has ganado Canicas");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No has ganado nada");
    }
```

Comment: No se deben responder preguntas que no cumplen los minimos de calidad. Y menos aun con respuestas que ni siquiera solucionan la problematica.